# Download in CSV File using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, csv, server

I am trying to convert MySQL table to csv and download it from server. i have uploaded this script on server.

```
 <?php  
  //export.php  
 require 'db_connection.php';

 header('Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8');  
 header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=data.csv');  
 $output = fopen("php://output", "w");  
 $sql = "select * from  tablaregistro";
 $stmt= $pdo->prepare($sql);
 $stmt->execute();
 while($row = $stmt->fetch())
 { 
    fputcsv($output, $row);  
 }  

 fclose($output);  
 ?>
```

This script is converting table to CSV and file is being downloaded in "data.csv" but when I upload this script to server, it is just displaying CSV on the whole page. It is not downloading like in localhost. I hope my question is clear.

Comment: so this is working when running on your local machine, but not when you upload to a remote server?

Comment: yes on localhost , file is downloaded with name data.csv but on server it is showing me like this : http://prntscr.com/khf642

Comment: Does same thing happen across different browsers?

Comment: Yes tried On Maxthon and same result :( . please help

Comment: its possible that the remote server it miss configured and not handling .csv mime types/files correctly

Comment: what can i do ?now

Comment: Where is the code to download CSV file?

Comment: i'm sorry but same code is working for me to download it on local server.but it is not working on live server

Comment: Set the content-disposition in the http header to force a download.

Comment: already set that , you can see in post. neither data.csv file is created in the file manager directory.

Comment: what happens if you upload a text.csv file to the server and try to download it via the browser?